# Documenting aliased anonymous class for code completion

Tags: php, phpstorm

An anonymous class:

```
$newClass = new class() {
  ...
};
```

... and an alias, so that the class can be instantiated in code:

```
class_alias(get_class($newClass), 'AliasName');
```

... like this:

```
$object = new AliasName();
```

Is there a way to document the class AliasName (not instances of it), so that autocomplete shows the class name (in PhpStorm)?

Something along this:

```
/** @class AliasName */     <– this is of course not working
```

Comment: No idea about PhpStorm, but I wonder if you could do AliasNameIntermediary for your class_alias, then properly define `class AliasName extends AliasNameMiddleGal`. Idk, all sounds like a headache lol. (I also haven't really used anonymous classes, so idk anything)

Comment: Try stubs approach (how the IDE knows about the PHP core classes): declare a class with the same name in `.php` file that will be for PhpStorm eyes only (it will not executed; just has to be located somewhere in the project/or referenced on the "Include Path" screen). Just as any other real class just with empty method bodies. PHPDoc comments can also be used (for typehinting, if necessary) Give it a try.